# How to change voice to male in pyttsx3

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I have written the code and it's working but only in a female voice. I want it to be the male voice.

```
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
```

this code is working but is in the female voice. Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for a voice named Alex

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
engine.setProperty('rate', rate + 1)
engine.setProperty('voice', 'com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Alex')
engine.say(voice)

engine.runAndWait()
```